# Autonomically link text across pages with different fonts

Tags: powerpoint

I work with a file with the same text but 4 different founts (and sizes) across 4 pages

and every time I have to copy and paste to reset them for multiple times is exhausting

is there a way to let the Text link one of the text box and I only have to type once ?

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't do this out of the box. You could write VBA macro or an add-in that would do the job for you, though.

Comment: Please ask programmable questions not powerpoint.